# Find empty cells and print their names in MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I am working on an archive system where a user lists information about a machine using data validation.

This information gets transferred to a table that looks like this:
| Unit | Machine | PC | Software | Who | Why |

To make the program function, the user must at least insert a machine .

I want the program to bar the user from logging information if they have not inserted information in either the PC, Software, Who, or Why field.
I also want a MsgBox that tells the user what they are missing.

I had two ideas for this.

The program could go through each cell and name it in its own MsgBox.

```vb
Sub InputCheck()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim shtForm As Worksheet

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set shtForm = wbk.Worksheets("Interface")

Dim MachFinder As Range
Dim itm, tbl
Dim listCols As ListColumns

Dim unit_input As String
Dim machine_input As String
Dim pc_inp As String
Dim software_inp As String
Dim who_inp As String
Dim why_inp As String

unit_input = shtForm.Range("A2").Value
machine_input = shtForm.Range("B2").Value
pc_inp = shtForm.Range("C2").Value
software_inp = shtForm.Range("D2").Value
who_inp = shtForm.Range("E2").Value
why_inp = shtForm.Range("F2").Value

Set tbl = randomTable

Set MachFinder = tbl.ListColumns("Machine").DataBodyRange.Find(machine_input, lookat:=xlWhole) 'Find machine name within table

If Not MachFinder Is Nothing Then
    'Check to see if a PC and software has been inputted
    If IsEmpty(pc_inp) Then
        pcRes = MsgBox("You did not insert the PC for this device." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If you ignore this warning, the machine will no longer be associated with any information, and it will be still be logged. Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbDefaultButton2, "Archive System")
        If pcRes = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
        
    If IsEmpty(software_inp) Then
        swRes = MsgBox("You did not insert the software associated with this device." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If you ignore this warning, the machine will no longer be associated with any information, and it will be still be logged. Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbDefaultButton2, "Archive System")
        If swRes = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
        
    'Check to see if user has inserted "Who" and "Why"
    If IsEmpty(who_inp) Then
        whoRes = MsgBox("You must put WHO worked on the device. Please put all information needed and try again.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Archive System")
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    If IsEmpty(why_inp) Then
        whyRes = MsgBox("There must be a reason for WHY there was work done on the machine. Please put all information needed and try again.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Archive System")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

My other idea is to consolidate them as a range. The program checks the range, finds the empty cells, and prints it in a MsgBox. I would need to name each cell in some way.

```vb
Dim inputs As Range
Dim inpite

Set inputs = shtForm.Range("C2:F2")

For Each inpite In inputs
    If IsEmpty(inpite.Value) Or inpite.Value = vbNullString Then
        ' I thought I properly named all of the cells within native Excel. It should reference the name of the cell. For instance, C2 is named "ComputerName"
        MsgBox "You are missing an entry for" & inputs.Names.Name & vbNewLine & "Please insert all correct information.", vbOKOnly, "Archive System"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

'blah blah blah, rest of program...
    
End If
```

I either get object assignment problems or its just, in general, not accepting the `IsEmpty` part of the program.

Comment: Range doesn't have `Names`. only  `Application, Workbook, Worksheet` have. And `Names` is a collection.

Comment: Ah, could I make a collection then using `Names.AddName`, and then do `Refers To` for a **specific cell only**?

Comment: First approach looks fine to me.

Comment: @TimWilliams Only thing is, whenever I run the code, it doesn't even register the command, it seems. It executes the rest of my program and ignores this part. I don't know if this is because the 'IsEmpty' function doesn't apply in the way I want it to. After the program runs, it runs a `.ClearContents` on that cell range. Do those cells become empty after a `ClearContents` gets ran?

Comment: Don't use `IsEmpty` but instead check the length - eg `If Len(pc_inp)=0 Then` as shown below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check For Blank Cells

[image]

**Main**

```vb
Sub YourProcedure()

    If Not IsFormInputValid Then Exit Sub
    
    MsgBox "Form input is valid. Continuing...", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

**Help**

```vb
Function IsFormInputValid() As Boolean
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Form Input Validation"
    
    Dim InputNames(): InputNames = VBA.Array("PC", "Software", "WHO", "WHY")
    
    Dim irg As Range:
    Set irg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Interface").Range("C2:F2")
    
    Dim cell As Range, c As Long, n As Long, MsgString As String
    
    For Each cell In irg.Cells
        If Len(CStr(cell.Value)) = 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            MsgString = MsgString & vbLf & n & ".) " & InputNames(c) _
                & " in cell " & cell.Address(0, 0) & ","
        End If
        c = c + 1
    Next cell
    
    If n = 0 Then
        IsFormInputValid = True
    Else
        MsgString = "You are missing the following entr" _
            & IIf(n = 1, "y", "ies") & ": " & vbLf _
            & Left(MsgString, Len(MsgString) - 1) & "." & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Please enter the required information."
        MsgBox MsgString, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If
  
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking blank cell with `Len(Trim(inputs.Cells(i)))`, then concate column header as popup message.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim inputs As Range
    Dim inpite, sMissing As String
    Set shtForm = ActiveSheet ' update sheet object as needed
    Set inputs = shtForm.Range("A2:F2")
    For i = 2 To 6
        If Len(Trim(inputs.Cells(i))) = 0 Then
            sMissing = sMissing & "," & _
                inputs.Offset(-1, 0).Cells(i).Value
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "You are missing entries: " & Mid(sMissing, 2) & _
        vbNewLine & "Please insert all correct information.", _
        vbOKOnly, "Archive System"
    Exit Sub
    ' your code
End Sub
```